# Is there a way to show an alert or a pop-up on device lock, even if the app is in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm really not sure if this is doable, but what I need to achieve is the following:

- Once the user locks the device, I want to show something intrusive on the screen, be it an alert or a pop-up of sorts, that needs to be there until the user dismisses it. The same should happen on every screen lock (or after x seconds of inactivity). This needs to happen when the app is in the background.

The app I'm developing is going to be an Enterpirse App, so I'm not worried about the review process. It's an app for physical stores for a telecommunications provider for demo devices, so we mean to show the device information and price on the device itself. The pop-up or alert is meant to showcase the price, and have the option to take the user to the app (where there will be more information displayed).

This is supposed to happen every time after the device is locked or inactive for some time, yet to be decided.

Moreover, if any of you know any information about demo iPhones, or some specifics that the software allows, let me know.

Any input or suggestion is appreciated!

I have already tried with local notifications and that works fine, but we are worried about the dead pixels that are somewhat known to appear after some time of displaying the notification (the screen would always be on, and the notification will be shown).